# How do I implement multiple root entities on a Blaze Persistence query?

Tags: java, blaze-persistence

According to [the Blaze Persistence Document](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/core/manual/en_US/#from-clause), a query could have multiple root entities. However, I could not find the way to do it. How do I implement multiple root entities on a Blaze Persistence query?

---

**Add**
**Solved problem:**

I implemented the following working test code thanks to Cristian.

```
    @Test
    void testThownExceptionWhenUsingRelativePathWithMultipleQueryRoots() {

        // @formatter:off
        IllegalArgumentException exception = assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
            CriteriaBuilder<String> cb = cbf.create(em, String.class)
                    .from(Cat.class, "c")
                    .from(Person.class, "p")
                    .select("name");
            List<String> cats = cb.getResultList();
        });
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call `.from(..)` multiple times.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer again! The problem was solved.